# Using Spring beans through IIOP protocol

Tags: java, spring, ejb

*It's possible to use Spring Beans through IIOP protocol (will be deployed on WebSphere)?*

I want to create Spring Bean that can be used by other applications in same application server. So easiest way is to create EJB for this purpose (EJB can be used over IIOP), but I want to do it with Spring.

Comment: You can always serialize a bean using IIOP.  It's not clear to me what you think Spring has to do with this.

Comment: @duffymo In other words, how I can access spring bean from another application? EJB's can be accessed by JNDI name, and communication between EJB and client will be through IIOP protocol (inside same server).